# How to filter minimongo collection with more parameters in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, minimongo

I need help with filtering reactively minimongo collection with 3+ parameters. Firs, I have loaded minimongo from server's mongo collection with publish/subscribe. Now, I want to filter that collection and let user see only objects from collection that are same like filters. First of all I have search query filter that checks if input string is same as some filed in collection:

```
Job.find({  $or: [ { Name: regex }, { Description: regex }, ]});
```

This part is doing his job well. And now second filter: I have field in object that is true if that particular job is remote friendly and false if it is not, I wanted to if user enables that filter he only see just remote friendly job positions, and if he disables that, he can see all jobs available ( + search query of course):

```
if (remoteQuery === true ) {
        return Job.find({  $or: [ { Name: regex }, { Description: regex }, ]  , Remote: true});
}
```

This is working, but it is bad way for doing this. And now biggest problem comes with last filter: I have one more field that is storing "job" (collection object) type. Type can be 1, 2 , 3 or 4. So how could I say to minimongo e.g. "Show only jobs that have "Front-end" inside (search query), that are remote friendly, and have third filter 2 and 3 inside"

```
Job.find({  $or: [ { Name: "Front-end"}, { Description: "Front-end"}, ]  , Remote: true, positionType: [2,3],});
```

Something like this? Thanks!

Comment: What is bad about your 2nd query?

Comment: Nothing is bad about second one, but I do not know how to filter third one. If user whants to see jobs with positionType 1 and 2 , or 1 and 3, or 1,2 and 4 how to search collection with that? Should I put this positionType in Array or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the MongoDB query [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator:

> The `$in` operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

Therefore your 3rd query could look like:

```
Job.find({
    positionType: {
        $in: [2, 3] // Matches documents where `positionType` is either 2 or 3
    },
    // Other conditions…
});
```

Comment: Okay, this could help, but I need cobination, and this 2,3 could also be 1,2,3 or nothing of those three.

Comment: Hey, thanks for everything, one more question: 
So, now I stored sucessfuly everything I wanted in array :
typeQuery

And now I want to use that array so I can find all colection that it's field have something from that array:

Job.find({  $or: [ { Name: regex }, { Description: regex }, ]  , Remote: true, positionType: typeQuery,});

How should I revrite this code?

Comment: Here is some rubber duck debugging ;)

This is correct way:
Job.find({  $or: [ { Name: "Front-end"}, { Description: "Front-end"}, ]  , Remote: true, positionType: { $in: typeQuery }}); 
 
Please update your answer with this. Thaks again!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I am glad you are ramping up your JS skills. Keep up the good work!